# Instantiate class in DLL throws a 127 error in LoadLibrary in QT

Tags: c++, qt, dll, eclipse-cdt

i'm trying to load a DLL in qt using LoadLibrary (only for test instead of QLibrary), the dll was compiled in eclipse CDT, but strangely when i try to instantiate any class in any function inside the Dll the LoadLibrary fails with error 127 (using GetLastError), but if i dont instantiate anything the LoadLibrary is successfuly, why happen this? my code is the next, the header and your implementation:

**Header:**

```
#ifndef DESKTOPWINUTILS_H_
#define DESKTOPWINUTILS_H_
#ifdef __dll__
#define DESKTOPUTILSEXP __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DESKTOPUTILSEXP __declspec(dllimport)
#endif  // __dll__
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "ximage.h"
#include "IDesktopUtils.h"
class DesktopUtils:public IDesktopUtils{
public:
    DesktopUtils();
    ~DesktopUtils(void);
    char* sayHello();
};
extern "C" DESKTOPUTILSEXP bool create(IDesktopUtils**);
#endif /* DESKTOPWINUTILS_H_ */
```

**Implementation:**

```
#define __dll__
#include "DesktopUtils.h"

DesktopUtils::DesktopUtils(){
    sayHello();
}

char* DesktopUtils::sayHello(){
    return (char *)("I say Hello");
}


bool create(IDesktopUtils** desktoputils){
    //DesktopUtils *desktoputils = new DesktopUtils();
    if(!desktoputils)
        return false;
    *desktoputils =(IDesktopUtils*) new DesktopUtils; //if comment this the load is successful
    return true;
}
```

In the qt project i use this for load the DLL, only for know if is loaded, i'm not even using GetProcAddress:

```
typedef char*(*createInst)(void);
    HINSTANCE dll;
    dll = LoadLibrary(TEXT("libDesktopWinUtils.dll"));
    if(dll){
        message.setText("library loaded");
        message.exec();

    }else{
        char error[10];
        itoa(GetLastError(),error,10);
        message.setText(error);
        message.exec();
    }
```

Comment: Please show the code that calls LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress.

Comment: thanks Adrian, that is, i am only testing the LoadLibrary.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the code you're commenting out creates a dependency that the system cannot resolve.  For example, the code that uses `new` requires that the system implementation for new either be already loaded into the process or that the DLL that provides it can be located and loaded.  If it can't then the LoadLibrary call will fail.

Ways to figure out missing dependencies:

- Run the program in a debugger that logs all of the modules that are loaded and unloaded.
- Use a dependency walker program.  (These are rare now that SxS has complicated the process.)
- Run something like Process Monitor while your program runs.  This will show exactly what DLLs are being searched for and where.

Comment: thanks, i use an application called "depends" that is a dependency walker and finds an strange error:

https://skydrive.live.com/embed?cid=3EB7B3AF5E9D51C0&resid=3EB7B3AF5E9D51C0%21211&authkey=ABAeGzz1vRH6z1s

strangely when i execute the .exe in my release or debug folder i get the message "library loaded" so that means to me that the application dont work, for some reason, inside the qt creator, or something like that, what can be? and thanks for your help.

Comment: yes i confirm it, i use the function sayHello in the Qt Application and works, this show me a dialog that say: "I say Hello" but only if i execute the .exe in the debug folder and not using the run option in Qt Creator.